# How to test Production Push Notification

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am using push notification in one of my application. Here I created SSL certificate for both development and production. I tested push notification for development successfully but now I want to test push notification for production . Can anyone tell me how to do this ?

Thanks For any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the APNS test app from Github: https://github.com/Zambiorix/Apple-Push-Notification-Test

The app will find your sandbox (development) and production certs in your keychain. Create a Release build for your app, the release build will use the production certificate by default. Use the APNS test app to push messages to the iPhone with the production cert.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang for development it is working but for production it gives error as : Error : Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL Code=-9844 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9844.)"

Comment: You could just restart the app and try again, the app is somewhat buggy. Also, make sure the device token is correct (should write it to console with NSLog and read the value when the iPhone is connected to your development Mac from the Xcode organizer console). Please note: production tokens are different from development tokens.